# can only be more applicable

Tags: meaning

I am not able to understand the meaning of the following sentence

> It can only be more applicable, now that a fresh law that aims for a greater transformative effect, the Rights of Persons with Disabilities Act, 2016, is in place.

[To Read Full Article](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/for-equal-treatment-the-hindu-editorial-on-the-supreme-court-extending-benefits-to-the-disabled/article32106048.ece?homepage=true)

Somebody help me understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd simplify it: "It can be applicable now that a law is in place." Next, add back the words that restrict it: "It can only be more applicable...."

The bits about "fresh law" (meaning new or newly revised law), its effect (greater transformation), and the law's name (The Rights of Persons with Disabilities Act, 2016) are not really necessary to understand the basic sentence.

So whatever the initial "it" is, this new law's enactment has made it (more) applicable.

Answer (score 1):

A fresh law has been put in place, that is, the Rights of Persons with Disabilities Act, 2016.

The sentence discusses the 1995 legislation, and how the above new law affects it.

The writer comes to the conclusion that the only effect that this new law can have upon that 1995 legislation is for it to apply even more strongly.